# How to update/edit custom_properties in laravel spatie?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm using laravel spatie in my app. I have a problem. 
When an user updates his list of image. Admin must to be approve a list of image which an user just update. If user add image, i just add more. But when an user change an image he had, how to do it? I can't change collection_name because if i change, this image is not appear in user profile. Do you have any ideal for me?
I have an ideal: i add an in custom_properties column with value `{'change' => 'false'}`. When user change this image, i will change custom_properties to `{'change' => 'true'}`. And when admin approve the change, i must update custom_properties to `{'change' => 'false'}`. But i can't access in value of custom_properties  column. (As you know, laravel spatie give us an media table , it has a column custom_properties have json data in it). So help me access in to this column and update data in it.

So sorry because my english is not good.

```
    $mediaOld = Media::where(['model_id' => $doctor_id, 'collection_name' => 'doctor_achieved'])->get();
    if (isset($mediaOld[$index])) {
        $mediaOld[$index]->update(['custom_properties->change' => 'true']);
        $mediaOld[$index]->save(); // Its not working 
        return $mediaOld[$index]->custom_properties; 
    }
```

This is data response of this record
[image: This is data response of this record]

Answer (score 5):

this might help:

```
$mediaItem = Media::find($id);

$mediaItem->setCustomProperty('name', 'value'); // adds a new custom propery or updates an existing one
$mediaItem->forgetCustomProperty('name'); // removes a custom propery

$mediaItem->save();
```

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/advanced-usage/using-custom-properties/

Comment: save() method is important here. In my case I forgot about it.